How to togg color of generated button on click. (Javascript HTML)
Trying to generate a button for each letter of the alphabet and then toggle the color from white to black on click.
function LoopTest() {
    var i = 0;
    var stop = 5;
    for (i = 65;i < 91;i++) {  
     var v = document.createElement('input');
     v.type="button";
     v.value= String.fromCharCode(i);
     v.id = i;
     v.style.color = "black";
     v.onClick = "changeColor(this.id)";
     document.getElementById('test').appendChild(v);
    }
}
function changeColor(_this){
    var pp = document.getElementById(_this);
    if(pp.style.color == "black"){
        pp.style.color = "white";
    }else{
        pp.style.color = "black";
    }
}

Generates the buttons fine by does nothing on click.

Have you tried addEventListener() instead of v.onClick?

any relevant code to demostrate the problem? HTML code and how are you calling those functions? you only gave us the definition of the funcions

Instead of setting an onClick property to a string of code, use addEventListener to add the click event.  For example:


function LoopTest() {
  var i = 0;
  var stop = 5;
  for (i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
    var v = document.createElement('input');
    v.type="button";
    v.value= String.fromCharCode(i);
    v.id = i;
    v.style.color = "black";
     
    // Here:
    //v.onClick = "changeColor(this.id)";
    v.addEventListener('click', function () {
      changeColor(this.id);
    });

    document.getElementById('test').appendChild(v);
  }
}

function changeColor(_this) {
  var pp = document.getElementById(_this);
  if (pp.style.color == "black") {
    pp.style.color = "white";
  } else {
    pp.style.color = "black";
  }
}

LoopTest();
<div id="test"></div>




Try to do: v.addEventListener(“click”, function() {changeColor(this.id)}); This should trigger the function when your button is clicked.
